# Associative array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ive come upon the following code and having trouble deciphering its use.

(changed up the variable names a bit for simplicity)

```
$fooo = array(

 'dog' => array('pages', 'home'),

 'cat' => array('users', 'login'),

 'bird' => array('users', 'reset', 1),

);
```

I am familiar with associative arrays but have not seen this "nested array" implementation before.

Is this code creating an array of arrays?

For example, `$fooo['dog']` returns an array where `$dog[0]='pages'` and `$dog[1]='home'`

That seems wrong.

Comment: Do: `print_r($fooo);` and look for yourself. (And is your question now how to access specific elements ?)

Comment: Do you mean `$foo = [
 'cat' => [
  'users' => "someValue",
  'login' => "anotherValue"
 ],
];` then `echo $foo['cat']['users'];`.

Comment: You get it right and there's nothing wrong about it. Arrays can hold items of any type, including other arrays.

Comment: Could you tell us what you think is wrong? The code does create an array of arrays. Or is it that you can just do `$dog[0]` to get the value and you actually expect to do `$fooo['dog'][0]`?

Comment: It seems right , print your array beautifully like ‛echo '<pre>'; print_r($fooo); echo '</pre'>;‛

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an array of arrays. But it perhaps may be more accurate to describe it as an associative array with an indexed array for every value.

The following can be done with it:

```
$fooo['dog'] // gets array("pages", "home")
$fooo['bird'][0] // gets "users"
$fooo['cat'][1] // gets "login"
$fooo['cow'] = array('x', 'y'); // adds another value to the outer array
$fooo['bird'][] = 2; // $fooo['bird'] now equals array('users', 'reset', 1, 2)
```

There is nothing wrong with this code, but your example is lacking practicality. There is plenty of code that uses such structures though. For example, a logical representation of a menu with sub-menus on a website (which seems like the source of your sample), this data structure can then be looped to generate an HTML/CSS menu.

Comment: thank you for your help! I get it now. And yes, I was having trouble getting values out of the sub-arrays and trying to understand that structure. The actual code looks like this and does seem to relate to a submenu. But how would one implement it as such?

Comment: @Mary624 either amend this to your original question, or I recommend creating a new quesiton

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.